# Java Nested for loop ( with if statement in inner for loop )

Tags: java, if-statement, nested-loops

I am trying to create a checkerboard with JavaFX. The rows and columns being determined by the input. The last box must be white. My code works if I start with an odd number but not if I start with an even number. I am not sure what is wrong with the if-else if statement. I have been staring at it for hours. Please help!

```
package application;    
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;    
/** 
    Java FX Hello World using a Label.
 */    
public class VG_CheckerBoard0 extends Application
{  
    int columnIndex, rowIndex;
    boolean nOdd;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {               
        //get n from user
        int n= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a number to make checkerboard: "));
         //create gridpane
        GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
        gridpane.setGridLinesVisible(true);

        // Create array of boxes 
        TextField[][] box = new TextField[n][n];             
        //set initial value of nOdd
        if ( n%2 == 0 ){
            nOdd = false;
        System.out.println(nOdd);
        }
        else {
            nOdd = true ;
        System.out.println(nOdd);
        }
        //populate array of boxes, set color and position for each
        for(int c= 0; c<box.length;c++){
             for(int r= 0; r<box.length;r++){
                 box[c][r] = new TextField("x");
                 //System.out.println(box[c][r]);

                     if (nOdd == true){

                         box[c][r].setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;" + "-fx-border-color: black;");

                         //switch for next iteration
                         System.out.println(nOdd + " - inside if true before ");
                         nOdd = false;
                         System.out.println(nOdd + " - inside if true after");
                     }else if (nOdd == false){
                         box[c][r].setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;" + "-fx-border-color: black;");

                        //switch for next iteration
                         System.out.println(nOdd + " + inside if false before");
                         nOdd = true;
                         System.out.println(nOdd + " + inside if false after");
                        }

                 gridpane.add(box[c][r], c, r);

             }//inner
         }//outer   

        // Set label as the root of scene graph.
        Scene scene = new Scene(gridpane);   
        stage.setScene(scene);

        // Set stage title and show the stage.
        stage.setTitle("Checkerboard");
        stage.show();
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }        
}
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT BELOW ( ODD NUMBER WORKS, CHECKERBOARD PATTERN). 
[image: ODD NUMBER WORKS AS EXPECTED]

[image: EVEN NUMBER DOES NOT WORK]

Comment: what the problem with an even number?

Comment: When even it will not alternate color on each textfield, it will be same color for entire row , so even number it alternates color every other row as approsed to every other box ( index of the multidimensional textbox array )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that since the outer loop is for the columns, and the number is identified as `even` it will alternate black and white for all the rows in that column but will reset for subsequent columns. So for example

```
initial value for nOdd = false
                            c = 0     c = 1 .. the process repeats again
                            |column 0|column 1|column 2|column3
it's alternating ------>    |black   |black                     nOdd = true
row-wise            |-->    |white   |white                     nOdd = false
                            |black   |black                     nOdd = true
                            |white   |white                     nOdd = false

nOdd came full circle so it starts back in black again
```

It works for odd because everything aligns correctly

```
initial value for nOdd = true
                            c = 0     c = 1 .. the process repeats again
                            |column 0|column 1|column 2
it's alternating ------>    |white   |black             nOdd = false
row-wise            |-->    |black   |white             nOdd = true
                            |white   |black             nOdd = false

nOdd started as true and ended as false so for the next column we get alternating colors
```

One quick fix is to check if `n` is indeed even once you've gone through all iterations of the inner loop and then `xor` the variable `nOdd` with `true` (a fancy way to say, "toggle" the value)

```
    for(int c= 0; c<box.length;c++){
         for(int r= 0; r<box.length;r++){
             box[c][r] = new TextField("x");
             //System.out.println(box[c][r]);

                 if (nOdd == true){

                     box[c][r].setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;" + "-fx-border-color: black;");

                     //switch for next iteration
                     System.out.println(nOdd + " - inside if true before ");
                     nOdd = false;
                     System.out.println(nOdd + " - inside if true after");
                 }else if (nOdd == false){
                     box[c][r].setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;" + "-fx-border-color: black;");

                    //switch for next iteration
                     System.out.println(nOdd + " + inside if false before");
                     nOdd = true;
                     System.out.println(nOdd + " + inside if false after");
                    }

             gridpane.add(box[c][r], c, r);

         }//inner
         if(n % 2 == 0) {
             nOdd = nOdd ^ true;
         }
     }//outer
```

You can also use the indexes `r` and `c` to decide the color of the cells. Minor detail, since Java  is row-major, it might be better to have `r` as the outer variable for large `n` but I'm assuming you don't expect to have huge values for `n` so don't worry about this too much.

Comment: awesome! thank you StaticBeagle! It took me a minute to understand! thank you for thorough explanation!

Comment: @Vynce82 glad I could help!